# Unable to get method to access characters in a String

Tags: java, android, android-studio, input, user-input

I am trying to make a Caesar Cipher app on Android Studio. I have the XML file and most of the other code ready but was unable to continue past the point in the code where I must access each element of the string. I have tried using the `charAt()` function.

Also I just want the character at the point in the array to increase by the number specified, I say this because I saw that after 'z' special characters like '|' appear and that is fine by me. This is my first app and could really use some help. The error is at line 47 and 61.

Here is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    EditText input;
    EditText output;
    EditText num;

    String inp;
    String out;
    int choice;
    Character c;

    Button enc, dec;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        output= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);
        num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);

        enc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enc);
        dec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dec);

        enc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                inp=input.getText().toString();
                choice= Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
                {
                    inp.charAt(i)= (char) (inp.charAt(i)+choice);
                }
            }
        });

        dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1)
            {
                inp=input.getText().toString();
                choice= Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
                {
                    inp.charAt(i)= (char) (inp.charAt(i)-choice);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @corsiKa's answer, I suggest the following. First, convert your input string into a `char[]`:

```
char[] array = inp.toCharArray();
```

Now you can iterate over the array and modify its contents:

```
array[i] = array[i] + choice;
```

And, at the end, you can build your output string from that array:

```
output.setText(new String(array));
```

Comment: Wow, yes sir. I guess this method was I was hoping for. I will try this out now and check if it works.

Comment: Note that the `array[i] + choice` is going to have so weird behavior - choice is an int, and array[i] is a char. This will indeed result in a char, but you must be concerned about overflow - if `array[i] == 'z'` what do you expect the value to be? You can probably do something like `if(array[i] + choice > 'z') choice -= 26` I suppose.

Comment: Yes sir, I did get a weird behaviour but I type casted it such that array[I]= (char) array[I]+choice;

Comment: Hello again sir, sorry for the delay I had some college exams for the last 3 days. I got to completing the app today and in the Android Studio IDE I have both the XML and the Main Java code without any errors. I then plugged in my phone for app Install and to check if it would work properly but it did not. Initially the app did not open, when I clicked on the app it used to load but later crash saying it had stopped working or the app kept crashing. Finally I have a stable version which takes both the input and output. But the problem is it crashes when I press the button Encrypt or Decrypt

Answer (score 1):

I believe your first problem is here:

```
inp.charAt(i)= (char) (inp.charAt(i)+choice);
```

You are trying to assign a value to a method return. This is not possible in Java.

Strings are immutable in Java - if you'd like to replace a value in a String, you must build a new String and resassign the reference that points to the old String to instead point to the new String.

There may be other issues that I have not had a chance to get to, but I believe this is the real issue. I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, so unfortunately I can't make a suggestion for what you should use instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So are you suggesting that I must create a new string and later assign the values to this string and continue the operation on the new string?